# Custom URL in Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I wanna add a suffix to my URL according to the `type` column in my database table.

```
# shop_controller.rb
...
def near
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  @type = @shop.type
end

# routes.rb
resources :spots do
  member do
    get :near
  end
end
```

Pages I have is currently in `app/views/shops/nearby.html.erb`. The url that is produced is currently:

```
http://localhost/shops/1/near
```

Instead of creating multiple pages for different types: `nearby_country.html.erb`, `nearby_state.html.erb`, `nearby_city.html.erb` which is not RESTful, I would prefer to append the type on this url to filter the shops by type, so that in future when I have more types it can automatically be shown:

```
http://localhost/shops/1/near_country
http://localhost/shops/1/near_state
http://localhost/shops/1/near_city
```

I also wanna be able to do the custom path for my menu like:

```
nearby_country_shop_path
nearby_state_shop_path
nearby_city_shop_path
```

Can anyone gimme some hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See section 3.1 in:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

but you'll probably have to use routes like:

```
http://localhost/shops/1/near?country
http://localhost/shops/1/near?state
http://localhost/shops/1/near?city
```

See also:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3

http://railscasts.com/episodes/231-routing-walkthrough

http://railscasts.com/episodes/232-routing-walkthrough-part-2

Comment: Is there anyway to append underscore instead: `near_country`?

Comment: Because I actually already have ?country for my `show.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but you could add a parameter `x` to your route, eg.

```
resources :spots do
  member do
    get 'near/:x', :action => :near, :as => :near
  end
end
```

This should give you URLs like:

```
/spots/1/near/country
/spots/1/near/state
/spots/1/near/city
```

.. and a route like:

```
near_spot GET /spots/:id/near/:x(.:format) {:action=>"near", :controller=>"spots"}
```

.. and url helpers like:

```
near_spot_path(spot_id, :country)
near_spot_path(spot_id, :state)
```

etc.